# Safe Harbor with EE2.8+

Tags: eeharbor

Does anyone know if Safe Harbor works with EE2.8+ or 2.9? I am contemplating purchasing this over Backup Pro by mithra62.

In actual fact I would like to know which is better as a ftp backup solution. I know that Backup Pro zips the files, does Safe Harbor compact the files too?

Answer (score 0):

Safe Harbour does work with 2.8 and 2.9. It compacts the files too such as .zip